# Fullcalendar v4 - Changing the color of the date number if there is an event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar v4 and I'm trying to change the color of the date number if there is an event (not the background). I can't figure out how to do it and I can't find anything in the docs.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share what you've got so far?

Comment: If there's an event on that day, it will show up anyway on the calendar on that date. You don't really need to change the colour, it will already be obvious.

Comment: But if you maybe only ever have one event per day or something, and you want to colour the whole cell, you could maybe display your events as [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) instead.

Comment: I haven't found anything (yet) to change the color of the number (the 2 or 3 for instance). I can have many events on the same day, so the background will "stack" and will get darker and darker, and then the number can't be read properly. So my plan what is to make that number white if there is an event on that date.